# java.lang.String cannot be cast to Ljava.lang.Object

Tags: java, jsf

To tentando listar itens em um ui:repeat que está dentro de outro, e preciso usar como parâmetro o id do item do ui:repeat mais externo. Mas não tô conseguindo fazer pois está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

**UI:REPEAT**

```
<ui:repeat var="itemRelato" value="#{livroOrdemController.relatos}" 
varStatus="status">

                <p:panel id="panelRelatos">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Data do Relato: "/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{itemRelato.dataOcorrencia}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                    <br />

                    <h:outputLabel value="Tipo do Relato: "/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{itemRelato.tipoRelato.descricao}"/>
                    <br />

                    <h:outputLabel value="Fase da Obra: "/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{itemRelato.faseObraServico.descricao}"/>
                    <br />

                    <h:outputLabel value="Inicio da Fase: "/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{itemRelato.dataIncioFase}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                    <br />

                    <h:outputLabel value="Términio da Fase: "/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{itemRelato.dataTerminioFase}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                    </h:outputText>
                    <br />

                    <h:outputLabel value="Descrição: "/><br />
                    <h:outputText value="#{itemRelato.descricao}"/>
                    <br />

                    <b>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Retificações/Complementos: "/>
                    </b>
                    <ui:repeat var="itemRetificacao" value="#{livroOrdemController.recuperarRetificacoes(itemRelato.idRelato)}"
                               varStatus="statusRetificacao">

                            <li>
                                <h:outputText value="#{itemRetificacao.descricao}"/>
                            </li>
                        </ui:repeat>

                    <br />

                    <p:commandButton value="Retificar Relato"
                                     update="#{livroOrdemController.componentes}"
                                     onclick="dialogRetificacao.show();"
                                     process="@this">

                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{itemRelato}" target="#{livroOrdemController.relatoASerRetificado}"/>


                    </p:commandButton>
```

**Método de Listagem no Controller**

```
public List<RetificacaoRelato> recuperarRetificacoes(Long idRelato) {
    List<RetificacaoRelato> retificacoes = new ArrayList<RetificacaoRelato>();
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    String queryRetificacoes = "SELECT rr.descricao FROM RetificacaoRelato rr "
            + "WHERE rr.relato_idrelato = :idrelato";
    params.put("idrelato", idRelato);

    List<Object[]> objects = objectDao.listPesqQuery(queryRetificacoes, params);

    for (Object[] o : objects) {
        RetificacaoRelato retificacaoRelatoTemp = new RetificacaoRelato();
        retificacaoRelatoTemp.setDescricao((String) o[0]);
        retificacoes.add(retificacaoRelatoTemp);
    }

    return retificacoes;
```

**Método listPesqQuery**

```
@Override
public List<T> listPesqQuery(String query, Map<String, Object> params) {
    Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(query);
    for (String chave : params.keySet()) {
        q.setParameter(chave, params.get(chave));
    }
    return q.getResultList();

}
```

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Object;` é o nome da classe `Object[]`. Suspeito que a função `objectDao.listPesqQuery` esteja retornando uma lista de  `String`s e não uma lista de `Object[]`. Poderia postar o código `objectDao.listPesqQuery` para confirmar?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o método

Comment: O método `Query.getResultList` retorna uma `List` sem tipo. Não sei como funciona esse método internamente, porém, como se trata de uma query que retorna somente um valor por registro, creio que ele consegue fazer o type casting pra `String` automaticamente; Caso você queria forçar um tipo de retorno, você pode usar a classe `TypedQuery`que implementa a interface `Query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substitua

```
retificacaoRelatoTemp.setDescricao((String) o[0]);
```

para

```
`retificacaoRelatoTemp.setDescricao(String.valueOf(o[0]));`
```

ou

```
retificacaoRelatoTemp.setDescricao(o[0].toString);
```

Comment: Obrigada, resolveu!